# Two pointers method in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How I can implement the two pointers method in haskell?

For example, in the subarray sum problem where we want to find a subarray whose sum is x.

Example : [ 1, 3, 5, 18 ]   Find subarray whose sum is 8. Ans: [3,5]

In imperative programming, the solution is given by the two pointers method by maintaining pointers to first and last value of subarray. And the right pointer moves when the resulting subarray sum is lteq to x.

The closest idea I've came up with is through a combination of `scanl` and `takeWhile`, but I wasn't able to visualize how to slide the 'worm' as we scan for the solution.

My naive implementation of the algo described

```
go' :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
go' x l 
    | null l = False
    | x `elem` takeWhile (<=x) (scanl' (+) 0 l) = True 
    | otherwise = go' x (tail l)
```

Comment: Can you post a link or some code that shows how the two pointers method works in an imperative language?

Comment: @Noughtmare In the competitive programming handbook, https://cses.fi/book.pdf . The subarray sum problem is described in the two pointers method section at page 77.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can always do is write a direct translation of the imperative code into Haskell:

```hs
import qualified Data.Vector as V

twoPointers :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
twoPointers x xs = go 0 0 0 where
  arr = V.fromList xs
  n = V.length arr
  go s l r
    | r  == n = Nothing
    | s' == x = Just (V.toList (V.slice l (r + 1 - l) arr))
    | s' <= x = go s' l (r + 1)
    | otherwise = go (s - arr V.! l) (l + 1) r
    where
      s' = s + arr V.! r
```

Edit: The following functional solution is not yet O(n), sorry.

For a more functional solution, I would derive it as follows. You already suggested `scanl` and `takeWhile`, I would combine it with `tails` to get a list of all the sums of each subsequence:

```hs
ghci> map (takeWhile (<= 5) . scanl (+) 0) (tails [1,2,3])
[[0,1,3],[0,2,5],[0,3],[0]]
```

(Note you can write it with the monadic bind instead: `takeWHile (<= 5) . scanl (+) 0 =<< tails [1,2,3]` which I think looks better)

With this we can easily solve the decision problem version where we just want to determine if there is a subsequence with a specific sum:

```hs
subseqSumDecision :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
subseqSumDecision x xs = x `elem` concatMap (takeWhile (<= x) . scanl (+) 0) (tails xs)
```

To get the actual subsequence, I think the easiest way is to change the arguments of `scanl` to also build up the subsequences:

```
ghci> concatMap (takeWhile ((<= 5) . fst) . scanl (\(s, xs) x -> (s + x, x : xs)) (0, [])) (tails [1,2,3])
[(0,[]),(1,[1]),(3,[2,1]),(0,[]),(2,[2]),(5,[3,2]),(0,[]),(3,[3]),(0,[])]
```

Now we can simply use the `lookup` function to find the subsequence:

```hs
subseqSumReversed :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
subseqSumReversed x xs = lookup x 
  $ concatMap
    (takeWhile ((<= x) . fst) . scanl (\(s, xs) x -> (s + x, x : xs))
    (0, []))
  $ tails xs
```

And you might notice that this returns the subsequence reversed, so you can simply reverse it again at the end:

```hs
subseqSum :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
subseqSum x xs = fmap reverse
  $ lookup x 
  $ concatMap
    (takeWhile ((<= x) . fst) . scanl (\(s, xs) x -> (s + x, x : xs))
    (0, []))
  $ tails xs
```

Comment: About the time complexity, I tried your first and second solution on a large test set which came from an interview I had recently and it wasn't even able to finish the first case. My scanl solution is similar to yours so it wasn't helpful as well.  I'm now trying to experiment with passing in scanl' to scanr and reason with it to see if that make any sense. 

The algorithm seemed simple enough to implement in C like language but I've spent the whole day trying to figure out how to describe it in Haskell.

Comment: I have updated the first solution a few times. Maybe you are using an old version. I think it should now have the right complexity.

Comment: Also be sure to compile with optimizations (`-O`).

Comment: The first solution didn't seem to be correct.  `twoPointers 4 [1,2,3,4]` crashes it

Comment: Oops, slices should be start and length and not start and end. I have fixed it. I guess I am suffering from [integer blindness](https://runtimeverification.com/blog/code-smell-boolean-blindness/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively straightforward way to solve the problem:

```hs
getSubarrayIndices :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
getSubarrayIndices target list = 
   let prefixSumsWithIndices = zip [0..] $ scanl' (+) 0 list
       loop begin@((beginIdx, beginSum):restBegin) end@((endIdx, endSum):restEnd) = 
            case compare (endSum - beginSum) target of
                LT -> loop begin restEnd
                EQ -> Just (beginIdx, endIdx)
                GT -> loop restBegin end
       loop _ _ = Nothing
   in loop prefixSumsWithIndices prefixSumsWithIndices
```

If `getSubarrayIndices target list = Just (beginIdx, endIdx)` then `target = sum (drop beginIdx (take endIdx list))`. If `getSubarrayIndices target list = Nothing` then there is no contiguous subsequence of `list` summing to `target`.

It's important to note that one should rarely use lists as a means for storing data. If you're looking for high performance, lists in Haskell should really be viewed as a replacement for control flow mechanisms in imperative languages, not as a means to store data that will be looped over multiple times. The asymptotic time complexity of using lists and using an array in this case will be equal, but the constant factors will favour the use of an array. In this case, we can actually improve the memory complexity of the algorithm by creating two copies of `prefixSumsWithIndices` as follows:

```hs
getSubarrayIndices :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
getSubarrayIndices target list = 
   let prefixSumsWithIndices () = zip [0..] $ scanl' (+) 0 list
       loop begin@((beginIdx, beginSum):restBegin) end@((endIdx, endSum):restEnd) = 
            case compare (endSum - beginSum) target of
                LT -> loop begin restEnd
                EQ -> Just (beginIdx, endIdx)
                GT -> loop restBegin end
       loop _ _ = Nothing
   in loop (prefixSumsWithIndices ()) (prefixSumsWithIndices ())
```

This is because in the original algorithm, when `end` gets ahead of `begin`, all the intermediate prefix sums are stored in memory somewhere. In the second version of the algorithm, which creates two lists, both lists will be produced as they are consumed, so there are no intermediate prefix sums to store as the intermediate prefix sums are recalculated by `begin`. Thus, our new code uses `O(1)` auxiliary memory.

Comment: Your attempt to save memory will likely be defeated if you enable optimizations.

Comment: @dfeuer GHC does not apply any "dangerous" optimizations even at `-O2`, which are optimizations that can increase the space or time complexity. These optimizations have to be turned on manually. So GHC should not be able to do common subexpression elimination here since it increases space complexity.

Comment: Look at `lvl_s2Ki` in [this Core](https://tio.run/##fZLbSsNAEIbv8xQ/VDCLTSleFiqi1hqprdKCF6WUbbJtFjcHshtsFZ89ziY9WKpOIJPZ@ebPzCQR129CqbL89BoYPU/80XA87z/cwhtdwgvDIs48LeNMoeF9OY4Tp2GhBO6ljvAeiVw4lExzgztueGsgtXGclTDjYsHznG/8JJSB0Oh04CcG3hWm5Gf24YlvFgIuhU2bY7@VGZ7TKRTJogsHgKIwy8VSrsdFrF@liXasywj5kBmm7VZrhjPogCfqHO4FQ7uSsPXWVJpmWIiVTK5dt/J@uG7WJ6TKOrnQ5sZGDCIJCaJ7hZDfA70kZNum9hZwLRCkccZzGq2m4R2UdwOly6Mya4OJXcqhNWzfcQL2Xiz4WNBKfjRfd8hO6P5Bdj@VhY92Maeri2FqIpmsbIaYKuH@tWr2T4p@Ek4C9pOPKK6jLrLC7oSV5Tc).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention a two-pointer method, we can actually use one. We'll keep one pointer to the first element of the subsequence, and one pointer just past the last. We'll also keep track of the size of the subsequence and its sum.

```hs
import Numeric.Natural

getSubarray :: Natural -> [Natural] -> Maybe [Natural]
getSubarray goal = \xs -> go 0 0 xs xs
  where
    go sz total start []
      | total == goal
        -- These shenanigans avoid leaking the remainer
        -- of the list.
      , (taken, !_) <- splitAt sz start
      = Just taken
      | otherwise = Nothing
    go sz total ~start@(a:as) end@(x : xs) = case compare total goal of
      EQ
        | (taken, !_) <- splitAt sz start
        -> Just taken
      LT -> go (sz + 1) (total + x) start xs
      GT -> go (sz - 1) (total - a) as end
```